# Iterative algorithms for sparsity using a function for operator A in Ax=b

Tags: sparse-matrix, iterative-method

I am going to solve an linear iterative inverse problem. I have two functions in `matlab` which one of them play the `forward` and the other play the `adjoint` role. I am not familiar with inverse problems very much and I am going to test some algorithms to check which one can help me to obtain a sparse model. Since I have to use my functions to do the forward and inverse operator roles in `Ax=b`, so I think I am not able to use some algorithms which needs `A` as a matrix. As an example, I could use the `linearized bregman`as follows:

$$
v^{k+1} = v^k + A^T(f-Au^k).
$$

$$
u^{k+1}= \delta * shrink(v^{k+1},1/\mu).
$$

in which, for `A` I use that function which transform the model `u` to the data space and for `A^T` the function which transform the data to the model space.

I want to know that is there any other iterative algorithm which can be used in this manner for sparsity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, most solvers for sparsity regularized least squares problems have been designed to use matrix-vector multiplications rather than accessing the matrix directly.  See for example SPGL1 at

http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~mpf/spgl1/

A good list of software for these kinds of problems can be found (at the very bottom of the page) at the Rice web site on resources for compressive sensing:

http://dsp.rice.edu/cs

Comment: I don't have the matrix `A`, instead I have a function as `A(u)` which gives `f'`

Comment: That's the point- with SPGL1 you can supply a subroutines which compute $A(u)$ and $A^{T}(v)$ rather than supplying the matrix itself.

Comment: How can I use it when I have two function, one for forward, A, and one for adjoint, A', since SPGL1 needs one function handle?

Comment: If you already have functions that compute $A(u)$ and $A^{T}(v)$, then you can write a wrapper function that simply checks the mode parameter and evaluates $A(u)$ if mode=1 and $A^{T}(v)$ if mode=2.